# Laravel job work command not working as before

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-queue

My application's job - queue was working smoothly. Supervisor was also works fine before. But in last couple of day this jobs are not processing as before..

*No error and nothing on logs file* [Edited]

Queue driver set on **Database**

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

also tried QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

[image: Job table]

So, I've tried manual work command in vps. Although same code's working on local machine and my test-server And as you can see.. Nothing appears

[image: php artisan queue:work]

also tried other commands

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=default --tries=1
```

Comment: what kind of errors do you get?

Comment: basically no error.. Nothing on logs too. Just not processing any job..

Comment: did you try a different queue driver like redis to exclude database issues? Maybe something is wrong with your db connection.

Comment: Are you sure that the jobs reached the available_at?

Comment: Can we see how you dispatch the job?

Comment: System is running now. @Lukas db connection is fine i guess..

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand how can i find that?

Comment: with something like   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Create podcast...

        ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast);
    }. please show how you dispatch the job for example in the controller

Comment: BulkOrderProcessJob::dispatch($this->authenticatedMember,$data, $orderer, $partner,$host);

Comment: are all variables set and valid? $this->authenticatedMember, $data,$ordered,$partner & $host?

Comment: yes they do... even same code's are working on my test sever.. But in couple of day earlier, database having an issue.. then mysql has been install again and imported that database. then this happened